# Queries related to implementing phase shift of sinusoidal wave after some time delay

Tags: vhdl

We are writing a vhdl code in which we are generating two sine waves, where we have to give particular phase shift(for example 170 degrees) to each of the waves after certain time and this process will occur repetitively (ie. after each 50 seconds there will be phase shifts of 170 degrees of the sine waves.)

We have tried to do the program.It runs up til a certain point. 
However when the value of i becomes greater than 359(there are 360 values in the array ), the simulation stops and its shows array index out of bounds error despite the fact that i has been reinitialised to 0 if value of i becomes >= 359.

We are including the simulation diagram upto which the simulation has occurred(After that simulation stops).And the arrow in the second diagram shows the point where the pointer marks in the program when the simulation ends.

[image]

[image]

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity digi_clk is
port (clk1 : in std_logic;
      seconds : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
      minutes : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
      hours : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

      data_out3 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
      data_out1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
      data_out2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
     );
end digi_clk;

architecture Behavioral of digi_clk is
signal sec,min,hour : integer range 0 to 60 :=0;
signal count : integer :=1;
signal clk : std_logic :='0';


signal i : integer :=0;
signal j : integer :=155;

type memory_type is array (0 to 359) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=(x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"06",
x"06",x"07",x"07",x"08",x"08",x"09",x"09",x"0a",x"0a",x"0b",
x"0b",x"0c",x"0c",x"0d",x"0d",x"0e",x"0e",x"0f",x"0f",x"10",
x"11",x"11",x"12",x"13",x"13",x"14",x"15",x"15",x"16",x"17",
x"18",x"18",x"19",x"1a",x"1b",x"1b",x"1c",x"1d",x"1e",x"1e",
x"1f",x"20",x"21",x"22",x"23",x"23",x"24",x"25",x"26",x"27",
x"28",x"29",x"2a",x"2b",x"2c",x"2d",x"2f",x"2f",x"30",x"31",
x"32",x"34",x"35",x"35",x"36",x"37",x"38",x"39",x"3a",x"3b",
x"3c",x"3c",x"3e",x"3f",x"40",x"41",x"42",x"43",x"44",x"45",
x"46",x"46",x"47",x"48",x"49",x"49",x"4a",x"4b",x"4c",x"4c",
x"4e",x"4f",x"4f",x"50",x"51",x"51",x"52",x"53",x"53",x"54",
x"55",x"55",x"56",x"57",x"57",x"58",x"58",x"59",x"59",x"5a",
x"5a",x"5b",x"5b",x"5c",x"5c",x"5d",x"5d",x"5e",x"5e",x"5f",
x"5f",x"5f",x"60",x"60",x"60",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"62",
x"62",x"62",x"62",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",
x"63",x"63",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"60",
x"60",x"60",x"5f",x"5f",x"5f",x"5e",x"5e",x"5d",x"5d",x"5c",
x"5c",x"5b",x"5b",x"5a",x"5a",x"59",x"59",x"58",x"58",x"57",
x"57",x"56",x"55",x"55",x"54",x"54",x"53",x"53",x"52",x"51",
x"51",x"50",x"4f",x"4f",x"4e",x"4d",x"4c",x"4c",x"4b",x"4a",
x"49",x"49",x"48",x"47",x"46",x"46",x"45",x"44",x"44",x"43",
x"42",x"41",x"41",x"40",x"3f",x"3e",x"3d",x"3c",x"3c",x"3b",
x"3a",x"39",x"38",x"37",x"36",x"35",x"35",x"34",x"33",x"32",
x"31",x"30",x"2f",x"2f",x"2e",x"2d",x"2c",x"2b",x"2a",x"29",
x"28",x"28",x"27",x"26",x"25",x"24",x"23",x"23",x"22",x"21",
x"20",x"1f",x"1e",x"1e",x"1d",x"1c",x"1b",x"1b",x"1a",x"19",
x"18",x"18",x"17",x"16",x"15",x"15",x"14",x"13",x"13",x"12",
x"11",x"11",x"10",x"0f",x"0f",x"0e",x"0d",x"0d",x"0c",x"0c",
x"0b",x"0b",x"0a",x"0a",x"09",x"09",x"08",x"08",x"07",x"07",
x"06",x"06",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00");


begin
seconds <= conv_std_logic_vector(sec,6);
minutes <= conv_std_logic_vector(min,6);
hours <= conv_std_logic_vector(hour,5);

 --clk generation.



process(clk1)
begin
if(clk1'event and clk1='1') then
count <=count+1;
if(count = 5) then --This is originally 50000000(for ease of viewing simulation results we have taken this a small no.).For 100 MHz clock this generates 1 Hz clock
clk <= not clk;
count <=1;
end if;
end if;
end process;

process(clk)   --period of clk is 1 second.
begin

if(clk'event and clk='1') then
sec <= sec+ 1;

--if(i >=359 or j>= 359) then
--i <=0;
--j <=0;
--end if;

data_out1 <= sine(i);-- after 20 us ;
data_out2 <= sine(j);

i <= i+ 1;
j <= j+ 1;

if(sec=50)then
i <= i+170;
if(i>=359)then
i<=0;
end if;
end if;

if(sec=100)then
i <= i+170;
if(i>=359)then
i<=0;
end if;
end if;

--if(sec=40)then
--i<= i+170;
--if(i>=359)then
--i<=0;
--end if;
--end if;

if(i >= 359) then
i <= 0;
end if;

if (j >= 359) then
j <= 0;
end if;


--if(sec = 59) then
--sec<=0;
min <= min + 1;
if(min = 59) then
hour <= hour + 1;
min <= 0;
if(hour = 23) then
hour <= 0;
end if;
end if;
--end if;
end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: We have taken the help of the following two websites for coding.

http://vhdlguru.blogspot.in/2010/03/...k-in-vhdl.html

http://vhdlguru.blogspot.in/2010/03/...r-in-vhdl.html

Comment: I think the idea of your code is to wrap around, i.e. use modulus 360 degrees. Now it does not do that. I.e. if i=e.g. 265, thus result should probably be i+170=265+170=435=75 degrees. But instead the result will now be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if(sec=50)then
    i <= i+170;
    if(i>=359)then
        i<=0;
    end if;
end if;
```

You should do something like:

```
if(sec=50)then
    i <= i+170;
    if(i+170>359)then
        i<=i+170-360;
    end if;
end if;
```

This will wrap 360 back around to 0 correctly.

Another option is to use 'binary degrees' instead, such that the full range of a power of 2 value corresponds to one full rotation. If you use a large counter, you can get a high resolution. The count value will then wrap around naturally on overflow, all you would need to do is convert your phase steps into the corresponding binary values. This technique is very common in direct digital synthesis/numerically controlled oscillators, which is basically what you're implementing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "i" is a signal not a variable, so its new value isn't immediately available. Therefore when you have something like

```
if(sec=50)then
    i <= i+170;
    if(i>=359)then
        i<=0;
    end if;
end if;
```

...

```
if(i >= 359) then
        i <= 0;
end if;
```

"i" can be set beyond the range of 359 if "i>189" and will not be read as such until the following clock cycle, therefore the checks are not doing what you expect.

You will want to change you ">= 359" to "<359" and when you perform your phase shifts compare to the minimum value that will cause a rollover AFTER the addition. So, at sec=50 and sec=100 use i>=189 as your condition.